# javascript regular expression to find single or double quote not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression to return false if special characters are found.  I'm trying to modify it to do the same if any single or double quotes are found.  This is one time that [regexr.com](http://regexr.com) is not helping.

Here is my expression that works for special characters:

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z]{2})((?!!|@|$|%|\^|&|\*)).)*$
```

Here is my regular expression for single and double quotes:

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z]{2})((?!'|").)*$
```

I even tried escaping them:

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z]{2})((?!\'|\").)*$
```

Please help!  I've wasted too much time on this and cannot quickly figure it out.

I have a method:

```
var isValidText = function (val) {
    var rx = new RegExp(\^(?=.*?[A-Z]{2})((?!!|@|$|%||^|&||*)).)*$\);
    var result = rx.text(val);
    return result;
}
```

Simple input:

> We're having a party and my house this weekend.  Please bring as many
>   friends as you like; the more the merrier.

This paragraph should be invalid as soon as it finds the single quote in We're.

Comment: Sorry, how does the first regex work?

Comment: The first one is not a valid regex, and why `[^"']` is not working for you?

Comment: Can you please explain why you are using the lookahead? From what you wrote, it should be as simple as `/'|"/.test(str)`, what am I missing?

Comment: The longer the regex the better.

Comment: I added the isValidText method to show how I'm using the regular expression.

Comment: @AlexCiminian - Perhaps you're correct that I don't need a lookahead.  The text can be a paragraph that needs to be invalid if any quotes are found.

Comment: @AlexBlex - your solution worked also.  I tested it in regexr and discovered that I needed to remove the ^ to find the existence of the quotes.  It worked in the javascript code as well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need for lookaround here, and since you're only matching single characters you can simply use a character set instead of `|`.

`.*[!@$%^&*'"].*`

Comment: This works great!  But I have to mention that Alex Blex's comment also worked once I removed the ^.  Thank you.